Check login authentication using ROOM and COMPOSE
My application uses navigation in conjunction with room and compose, my problem is that when starting the app, a check is made in the local database and if the user has selected an option to remember login, the application should redirect directly to the home screen , but during bank verification there is a processing time in which compose renders the login screen for a fraction of time and then redirects to the correct screen. Would there be a suitable way to start the application without this display?
The correct thing to do is check at the bank and redirect directly to the home screen.

@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {

    val viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val login by viewModel.login.collectAsState()
    val initialRoute = if (login) AppGraph.home.ROOT else AppGraph.auth.ROOT

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            route = AppGraph.initial.ROOT,
            startDestination = initialRoute
        ) {
            homeNavGraph(navController = navController)
            authNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }
}


@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
    private val loginRepository: LoginRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val scope = viewModelScope
    
    private val _login = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val login: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = _login

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            checkLogin()
        }
    }
    

    suspend fun checkLogin() {
        try {
            val res = loginRepository.getLastLogin()
            if (res.checked == true) {
                _login.value = true
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _login.value = false
        }
    }

    suspend fun logout() {
        val res = loginRepository.getLastLogin()
        res.checked = false
        loginRepository.setChecked(res)
        _login.value = false
    }
}


You need to create a loading screen and make it the default start destination.
Then create an enum with 3 values (Checking, LoggedIn, LoggedOut)
A simple example
@Composable
fun WaitingScreen() {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}

enum class LoginStatus {
    Checking,
    LoggedIn,
    LoggedOut
}

Next, in your viewmodel
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val loginRepository: LoginRepository
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _loginStatus = MutableStateFlow(LoginStatus.Checking) // here I am making the waiting screen the default until logging status is known
    val loginStatus: StateFlow<LoginStatus> = _loginStatus.asStateFlow()

    init {
        checkLogin()
    }


    fun checkLogin() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val res = loginRepository.getLastLogin()
                if (res.checked == true) {
                    _loginStatus.value = LoginStatus.LoggedIn
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _loginStatus.value = LoginStatus.LoggedOut
            }
        }
    }

    fun logout() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val res = loginRepository.getLastLogin()
            res.checked = false
            loginRepository.setChecked(res)
            _loginStatus.value = LoginStatus.LoggedOut
        }
    }
}

Now, in your RootNavigationGraph
@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {

    val viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val logingStatus by viewModel.logingStatus.collectAsState()
    val initialRoute = when (logingStatus) {
        LoginStatus.Checking -> TODO("Your route for waiting screen")
        LoginStatus.LoggedIn -> AppGraph.home.ROOT
        LoginStatus.LoggedOut -> AppGraph.auth.ROOT
    }

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            route = AppGraph.initial.ROOT,
            startDestination = initialRoute
        ) {
            homeNavGraph(navController = navController)
            authNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }
}


